# NullPointerException when trying to save data using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Iam new to hibernate.Now trying to save user details to my db using hibernate.For that i created 3 .java files.

1.First is HiberUtil.java.The code is as follows
package hiberpack;

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HiberUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

2.next is the DbMap.java

```
package hiberpack;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    //import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_details")
    public class DbMap {


        @Id
        //@GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id_auto;

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "Smobile", nullable=false)
        private String mobnum;

        public long getId_auto() {
            return id_auto;
        }

        public void setId_auto(long id_auto) {
            this.id_auto = id_auto;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getMobnum() {
            return mobnum;
        }

        public void setMobnum(String mobnum) {
            this.mobnum = mobnum;
        }


    }
```

3.Below is the UserSave servlet

```
package servlets;
    import hiberpack.DbMap;
    import hiberrepo.Repository;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class UserSave extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            Repository rep = new Repository();
            String name = request.getParameter("uname");
            String mp = request.getParameter("mob");
            DbMap st = new hiberpack.DbMap();
            st.setUsername(name);
            st.setMobnum(mp);
            rep.insertStock(st); 


        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

4.Below is the Repository.java

```
package hiberrepo;

import hiberpack.HiberUtil;
import hiberpack.DbMap;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Repository {
        SessionFactory sf = HiberUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session sfSession = null;

        public void insertStock(DbMap storeObj)
        {
            sfSession.save(storeObj);
        }
}
```

It shows Null pointer exception wen i tried to enter data into db using hibernate.The error message is as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        hiberrepo.Repository.insertStock(Repository.java:15)
        servlets.UserSave.doPost(UserSave.java:25)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Read the exception stack trace: The error occurs at line 15 of Repository.java. Yet that's the only class that you don't show us in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet Thats the repository file.Thanx in advance... :)

Answer (score 1):

`sfSession`is null when you call `Repository.insertStock()`. You definitively forgot to set the session. (The null pointer exception does not have anything to do with `DbMap storeObj`. The exception is thrown before the save method is entered.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
Session sfSession = null;
...
sfSession.save(...)
```

You can't call a method on a null reference. Initialize your sfSession variable.

PS: Hibernate is a very complex beast to understand and use. If you don't know that you can't call a method on a null reference, and fail to diagnose such a basic bug, I would advise you to learn programming in Java with more simple problems than a web app using Hibernate.

Comment: can u xplain in detail?how to initialise it and al?

Comment: This depends on your architecture, your design choices, the environment you run in (JTA? non-JTA? Spring?), the transactional boundaries. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions. But as I said, this shouldn't be handled by a Java newbie because it's too complex.

Comment: got it fixed.It was my first hibernate project.Thank u for the help